# How to know the remaining monthly payments based on the amount received?

Tags: php

If I input an amount of P200,000 then my monthly payments are the following:

```
###############################
# Monthly Payments ## Remarks #
###############################
# 43,590           ## Pending #
# 43,590           ## Pending #
# 43,590           ## Pending #
# 43,590           ## Pending #
# 43,590           ## Pending #
###############################
```

My monthly payments are in array. Then, how will I know if how many Monthly payments will covered on P200,000 and change the remarks to 'ENCASHED'?

I want the result like this:

```
###############################
# Monthly Payments ## Remarks #
###############################
# 43,590           ## Encashed#
# 43,590           ## Encashed#
# 43,590           ## Encashed#
# 43,590           ## Encashed#
# 43,590           ## Pending #
###############################
```

How do I code this on PHP?

Comment: How you splitting 200,000 to installments and show us the array you having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over payments and subtract sum of each payment from total sum until there is enough money:

```
// Just testing initialization
$payments = array_fill(0, 5, array('sum' => 43590, 'status' => 'Pending')); 
$totalSum = 200000;

foreach ($payments AS &$payment) {
  if ($totalSum >= $payment['sum']) {
    $totalSum -= $payment['sum'];
    $payment['status'] = 'Encashed';
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

See: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/nqe-yfd